# How to remove decenders from font inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, logo

Using a font called cabin, would like to remove all decenders for logo building purposes. Have tried using text-decoration-skip in css editor. To no avail.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you share an image showing what you are actually trying to do?  Inkscape can't modify fonts. However you can covert text to outlines, and edit the outlines manually, or use boolean operations to cut pieces off, or use clipping masks, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Descenders** are *not* "text decorations". There's no "setting", button, or CSS property, which will change the inherent display of glyphs containing descenders.

They are part of the artwork used to create a specific glyph.

- A `p` is not a `p` without its descender.
- A `y` is a `v` without its descender.
- A `g` is not a `g` (or it's an `a`) without its descender.
- A `j` is an `i` without its descender.

If you wish to alter the glyphs of a typeface, you need to create artwork or outline the type glyphs, and them *manually* change the glyph.

**Convert your text to outlines**, then adjust the resulting paths how you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an open type font feature that you want to turn on and off, check the Text and Font dialog, second tab 'Features'.

[image]